# SFINAE not working although template methods are used

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, type-traits

Consider the following code that tries to use SFINAE for providing different method implementations depending on a template parameter.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<bool S>
struct C{

     template<typename std::enable_if<!S>::type* = nullptr>
     int foo(int i){
         return i + 1;
      }

     template<typename std::enable_if<S>::type* = nullptr>
     int foo(int i){
        return i;
     }

};

int main(){
     C<true> c1;
     C<false> c2;
     std::cout << c1.foo(0) << c2.foo(0) << std::endl;
}
```

This example is inspired by the reference page of `std::enable_if`. As you see, struct `C<S>` has two `foo` methods. One should be enabled if `S` is `true`, and the other if `S` is `false`. However, the code does not compile but raises the following errors:

```
src/test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct C<true>’:
src/test.cpp:19:12:   required from here
src/test.cpp:7:8: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
    int foo(int i){
        ^
src/test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct C<false>’:
src/test.cpp:20:13:   required from here
src/test.cpp:12:8: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
    int foo(int i){
```

So it seems that the compiler completelty ignores SFINAE and raises an error once it finds that a type is not enabled. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @ecatmur: This is no duplicate. The other question clearly uses no template methods which is the source for its error. My methods ARE template methods so the answers to the other questions do not work for this question. It is quite insulting to simply duplicate-close a question just because the question titles sound similar. With great (moderation) power comes great responsibility, i.e., please thoroughly read questions before insta-closing them.

Comment: (I was wrong in how I worded this comment earlier.) `std::enable_if<S>::type` doesn't depend on any of the method's template parameters, because `S` is a template parameter of the class, not of the method.

Comment: @hvd: Then, what are these methods? After all, they have a template directive above their definition.

Comment: You're right that it's a template method, I edited my earlier comment (prior to your reply) when I noticed that how I worded it was just plain wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  template<typename std::enable_if<!S>::type* = nullptr>
  int foo(int i)
  {
     return i + 1;
  }
```

This is NOT function template, because there is NO *template parameter* for this (supposedly) function template. It is not even function. The code is simply ill-formed.

**Note that `S` is a template parameter of the *enclosing* class template, not the function (template).** 
The following code would be correct (but wouldn't solve your problem):

```
  template<typename SS, typename std::enable_if<!SS>::type* = nullptr>
  int foo(int i)
  {
     //etc
  }
```

Here `typename SS` defines template parameter for the function template. Your function doesn't do so. The template parameter used in `std::enable_if` must be a template parameter of the *same* function template.

---

Use function overloading to solve your problem:

```
template<bool S>
struct C
{

    int foo(int i)
    {
       return foo_impl(std::integral_constant<bool, S>(), i);
    }
private:
     int foo_impl(std::true_type, int i)
     {
         return i + 1;
     }
     int foo_impl(std::false_type, int i)
     {
        return i;
     }
};
```

That is the general implementation. But in this specific case, when you're using `bool` as template parameter, then another solution could be this:

```
template<bool S>
struct C
{

    int foo(int i)
    {
       return S ? foo_a(i) : foo_b(i);
    }
private:
     int foo_a(int i)
     {
         return i + 1;
     }
     int foo_b(int i)
     {
        return i;
     }
};
```

Since `S` is known to the compiler, so I believe the compiler would eliminate the branching in `return S ? foo_a(i) : foo_b(i);` and would instead write either `return foo_a(i);` or `return foo_b(i);` based on the value of `S`, effectively producing faster code.

Comment: Then, how can I change my code so that the fact I want to achieve (overloading based on template parameter of enclosing class) works?

Comment: I also commented on the question that this isn't a function template, but of course that's incorrect. It is a function template, and it does have a template parameter.

Comment: @Nawaz: If the code is ill-formed, then why does the reference page of `std::enable_if` do it similarly: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if the example code for `foo3`

Comment: @gexicide: It does NOT do the same thing. See again. There is `T` which is the template parameter.

Comment: Okay, so what is the general rule here? Is it that the code in the template parameter declaration must depend on another template parameter of the method?

Comment: @gexicide: Yes. The template parameter used in `std::enable_if` must be a template parameter of the *same* function template.

Answer (score 3):

`S` is not a template parameter of the method, it is a template parameter of the class. During instantiation of the class, `S` has been determined, and as a result, `std::enable_if<!S_>::type` is no longer type-dependent so cannot be used the way you're using it. You can, as Nawaz answered, solve this by using overloading, but you can also make `S` a template parameter of the method -- sort of:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<bool S>
struct C {
  template<bool S_ = S, typename std::enable_if<!S_>::type* = nullptr>
  int foo(int i){
    return i + 1;
  }

  template<bool S_ = S, typename std::enable_if<S_>::type* = nullptr>
  int foo(int i) {
    return i;
  }
};

int main(){
  C<true> c1;
  C<false> c2;
  std::cout << c1.foo(0) << c2.foo(0) << std::endl;
}
```